# Can we apply a SVG filter to a specific portion of canvas element?

Tags: jquery, canvas, svg, svg-filters

I was studying SVG and filters and then I had this thought: Can we apply filter to the specific portion of an element?

To be precise, have a look at: [My home page](http://pardhu225.github.io)

The squares are being drawn on two canvas on which flank the page. Now, as you can see there are a few squares which are below the main content. I want them to be blurred a bit so that it looks better.

**My Idea**:
Apply SVG blur filter to only that part of canvas which is directly under the main content.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If you have a specific question about SVG capabilities, please create a [mcve] and include it in your question.

Comment: I can't inspect your page right now, but are you using html `<canvas>` elements? If not please remove the canvas tag of your question. And in any case, previous comment is right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 2D context `filter` property

You can apply some standard filters to the canvas via the 2D context filter property.

#### `ctx.filter = "blur(5px)"`

The filter is applied to newly rendered content, not to the existing content.

```
ctx.fillRect(10,10,20,10); // not blurred

ctx.filter = "blur (5px)";
ctx.fillRect(10,30,20,10); //blurred but first rect remains unblurred
```

There are some built in filters. The units are like CSS and must be post fixed. Lengths "px", percent "%", degree "deg"

You can also use SVG filters via a url. I have never tried to use that method but assume i will cover all the SVG filters available.

When I first used filter property it was very slow. But now I am using them in animations as performance is getting way better. But do be careful as they are not yet up to CSS and SVG performance, generally because of render management techniques.

#### List of canvas filter methods.

```
"url(url)" // url points to XML file containing SVG filter,
           // can be to anchor in SVG  to filter element.
"blur(length)"
"brightness(percentage)"
"contrast(percentage)"
"drop-shadow(offsetX, offsetY, blurRadius, color)"
"grayscale(percentage)"
'hue-rotate(degree)"
"invert(percentage)"
"opacity(percentage)"
"saturate(percentage)"
"sepia(percentage)"
```

*Note; `filter` is experimental, see [MDN 2D context filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/filter)

Re SVG filter `url()` function. From MDN Sep 15, 2017

> - *url(). The url() function takes the location of an XML file that specifies an SVG filter, and may include an anchor to a specific
>   filter element.*

Also see [HTML Living Standard 4.12.5.1.19 Filters](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#filters) 3 October 2017

Comment: Not sure if question uses *canvas* as the rendering area of an svg graphic or really as the HTMLCanvas element, so you might be answering the wrong question. Also `url` points to an svgFilter element, not to a file, even though this filter can be embedded in an external file. And you might also want to add that filters can be combined.

Comment: Not too sure how I should take your edit... I'll take it personally and guess you trust more previous erroneous MDN statement than my correction, and thus I will lead you to the specs: https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#FilterProperty

Comment: This worked. Thanks for the answer! 
I need to point out that there should be no space between blur and ()

Comment: @Kaiido In my answer re the edit you comment on. I did not remove the reference to the MDN page (containing your update), The update to MDN has not made using `ctx.filter = "url(url)";` any clearer. I added the MDN quote to clarify my paraphrased description. BTW we are referring to the canvas 2D context and rendering using a SVG filter. I provided the reference to the correct spec in my edit.

Comment: My edit fixes an error, that I kindly pointed to you too: `url(url)` is a filter-function-property, part of a filter-function-list and **must** point to an SVG filter element as defined [here](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#typedef-filter-function-list). Your link defines the CanvasRenderingContext2D#filter property, and if you follow the links there you'll see I'm right. And you forgot an important part while paraphrasing this article: *The filter property accepts one **or more** of the following filter functions*

Answer (score 0):

You can filter a sub-section of your content using a feFlood as a pseudo-clippath. The filter window is defined by the dimensions specified in the feFlood.

```
    <svg>
      <defs>
      <filter id="partblur" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <feFlood x="0.1" y="0.1" width="0.2" height="0.35"/>
        <feComposite operator="in" in="SourceGraphic"/>
        <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
        <feComposite operator="over" in2="SourceGraphic"/>
      </filter>
      </defs>
    </svg>
```